# How to create file in Ubuntu terminal, specifying the content?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, cmd, terminal

Can I use a single command to create a file called "Procfile" and its content will be :

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

How can I do this in Linux terminal? Also, an answer for the windows command line (cmd) would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

For a single line file you can simply use `echo`:

```
echo "web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -" > Procfile
```

For a multiline file you can use echo multiple times while using append operator `>>`:

```
echo "line1" > Procfile
echo "line2" >> Procfile
...
```

If you have stored the text in a string you can use echo `-e`, like this:

```
str="foo\nbar"
echo -e "$str"
```

---

Also you can use `cat` and bash's [input output redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) together with a [`here-document`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for the content:

```
cat > "Procfile" <<EOF
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. +1. But for some reason, I'm afraid of heredocs, I tried to deal with them with PHP in the past, and I got errors. Also, is there a way to make multi-line without editing the original content?

Comment: What do you mean with `Also, is there a way to make multi-line without editing the original content?`

Comment: Because in the multi-line version, I will have to convert `"line1\nline2"` to `"echo "line1" > Procfile\necho "line2" etc"` right? i.e. it will became multiple commands, whereas I want a single command to make the job.

Comment: You can use `-e`. Like this: `echo -e "foo\nbar"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
cat > Procfile
Line 1
Line 2
<CTRL+D>
```